# i am trying to create a click listener that will open a new activity once it it clicked

Tags: java, android, layout, android-recyclerview

i ma trying to make a `recyclerview` clickable with an intent. the data will be extracted from `firebase` unto the `recyclerview`. but when i run the code, i get the error `cannot resolve symbol` `findViewById(int)`". This error happens at the fourth line of the `onBindViewHolder()`. This is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="textview"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="textview"
            android:clickable="true"/>



        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> and this is my Adapter

```
package com.example.helpresponse;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TargetDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TargetDataAdapter.TargetViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<AndroidTargets> targetsArrayList;
    private Context context;
   // View myClickableView;
    public TargetDataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidTargets> mTargetData) {
        targetsArrayList = mTargetData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TargetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.target_row,viewGroup,false);
        return new TargetViewHolder(v);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TargetViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.androidTargetName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD1 );
        viewHolder.androidTargetNumber.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "API Level: %d", targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD2));
        viewHolder.androidTargetShortName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD3);
        View myClickableView = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        //myClickableView.setClickable(true);
        myClickableView.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
            int myData = 1;
            intent.putExtra("myDataKey", myData);
            //more intent.putExtra(s) as needed
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(targetsArrayList == null)
            return 0;
        return targetsArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class TargetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView androidTargetName;
        protected TextView androidTargetNumber;
        protected TextView androidTargetShortName;

        public TargetViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            androidTargetShortName=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            androidTargetName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            androidTargetNumber= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        }
    }





}
```

i want to know what i am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hi below line is causing the issue.

```
View myClickableView = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

it should in itemview.

Comment: Sure look for you onBindAdapter code you are setting findviewbyId inside this method but you should do this inside TargetViewHolder  where you are setting all ids. Hope you got the point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this 'myclickableView' inside your TargetViewHolder class too

```
public static class TargetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView androidTargetName;
    protected TextView androidTargetNumber;
    protected TextView androidTargetShortName;
    protected LinearLayout myClickableView;
    public TargetViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        androidTargetShortName=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        androidTargetName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        androidTargetNumber= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        myClickableView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    }
```

only then you can use it inside onBindViewHolder method safely

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TargetViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.androidTargetName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD1 );
    viewHolder.androidTargetNumber.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "API Level: %d", targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD2));
    viewHolder.androidTargetShortName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD3);

    //myClickableView.setClickable(true);
    viewHolder.myClickableView.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
        int myData = 1;
        intent.putExtra("myDataKey", myData);
        //more intent.putExtra(s) as needed
        context.startActivity(intent);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define 'myclickableView' inside your TargetViewHolder class and use onClickListener

```
public static class TargetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implement View.OnClickListener{
    protected TextView androidTargetName;
    protected TextView androidTargetNumber;
    protected TextView androidTargetShortName;
    protected LinearLayout myClickableView;
    public TargetViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        androidTargetShortName=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        androidTargetName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        androidTargetNumber= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        myClickableView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        myClickableView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.linearLayout:
                //Do whatever you want
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i get an error "error: incompatible types: TargetViewHolder cannot be converted to OnClickListener
"